# Spring boot - @Service class calling another @Service class

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it fine to have a `@Service` annotated class calling another `@Service` annotated class? Or it is a bad practice?

Eg.:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    // ...
    
    @Autowired
    private MyOtherService myOtherService;
    
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is not any restriction calling a service from another one. Unless you make circular dependency between services.

Circular dependency : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Circular dependency in spring : https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Answer (score 12):

Its good practice since utility class are being ignored these days, approach getting motivated by horizontal scaling... Surely services got to interact with other.

No need to worry, its like one service manager needs services of another manager.

just only one should be dependent on other, not both.

Answer (score -6):

```
@Service
public class MyService {
// ...  
@Autowired
private MyOtherService myOtherService = new MyOtherService();
// ...}
```

Try this. It is worked for me. You can use the methods of a service in many sevice.

Comment: The `Autowired` annotation does not make any sense, if you instantiate the object directly anyway.