# Spring bood - @Service call another @Service

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am wondering is it a bad practice that @service call another @service.

Codes below are just an example.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class OrderService {
    private final ProductService productService;
    private final PayService payService;
    private final DeliveryService deliverService;
    
    public void createOrder(){
         //some codes.........
         productService.getProductList();

         //some codes.........
         payService.pay();

         //some codes.........
         deliveryService.deliver();
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ProductService {
    public List<productDto> getProductList(){
         //some codes.........
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class PayService {
    public void pay(){
         //some codes.........
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class DeliveryService {
    public void deliver(){
         //some codes.........
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////
```

I am currently studying about design patterns.
Some of my colleagues told me to use facade pattern, while others told me it is not a good practice to call another services in a service.
I want to know what is the best design patterns for the example codes above.

i am so welcome for any answers

Comment: Nope! It isn't bad practice. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51988237/9349240

Comment: Design patterns are the best practises which are derived from experience. @Service is just stereotype annotation. So if service can integrate multiple helpers than service can inject multiple services as well. Spring is not going to limit you. Of course, One needs to always take care about cyclic references. There are no borderline what one has to follow.

Comment: @ak.leimrey first of all, thanks your comment. 
I've already read it before. that question was more than 4yrs ago. therefore, i was wondering what is the trendy design pattern nowadays.

Comment: @UtkarshBhavsar Also thanks your opinion. now i have to see the cyclic references.

Comment: I don't notice massive changes in trends regarding patters. It's the application and understanding of said patterns that give them value. Don't get too hung up on of something is trendy or not. Especially in java, you won't see crazy changes anytime soon.